# HTML: Embed binary images without base64 compression

Tags: html, image, web, base64, embed

I have a tool that generates "standalone" HTML pages, which include embedded images.

I use binary representation of the images using **base64** encoding and it works, but when there are a lot of such images in the HTML pages, **it takes a 10sec while until !anything! is shown on the browser**. But really, **nothing** is shown until everything is loaded, unlike pages with URL directed images, in which the images are loaded while the rest of the page is already shown.

Answering 1 or more of the below questions would really help me:

1. Do you know a way to tell the browsers to load the images while showing the rest of the page, like it does for images with URL?
2. Do you know a way to to accelerate the decoding?
3. Do you know another way (else to base64) to represent binary data inside the HTML page, which has a weaker compression in comparison to base64, or which is not compressed at all, so it can be decoded faster by the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: 4. Should I use embedded images? Ans. No.

Comment: The answer to all your question is `NO`. `HTML` is pure text based. so no binary data. when you are base64 encoding your binary data is converted to string and the browser is decoding it back for you.

Comment: But these are standalone pages that should also work offline

Comment: Your comments are oriented of web-apps scenarios. But my scenario is not a webapp. In my case, I generate static reports in HTML format and send them by mail. They should work offline, like Word, Excel or any other formatted document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally answering myself....

So introducing again the problem:

- There are a lot of embedded binary images and it takes a lot of time to decode all of them
- While the JavaScript code is running (and decoding), nothing is refreshed on the screen. You have to wait until it is all done

The solution (you can call it a workaround):

- Delaying the script from time to time, letting the HTML be updated gradually at these delays, using the JavaScript function `setTimeout()`.

This way I can start browsing my HTML document at the first **~10sec**, while the pictures are loaded gradually